# Safari on my Mac won't open because "Safari cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer"

Tags: macos, safari

I have an error message, which has already been reported but I can't understand how to fix it.

I have Yosemite and there's no updates available except for iPhoto, which also can't be updated. I'm also locked out of Safari and all of my Favorites. I don't know if they're backed up in iCloud, but I'm really worried about this. Can anyone help me by providing the dumbed-down version? Here is the message I get:

> **Safari cannot be opened because of a problem.**
>
> Check with the developer to make sure Safari works with this version
>   of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install
>   any available updates for the application and OS X.
>
> Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to
>   Apple.

Restarting the computer does nothing, and I'm afraid to reinstall without knowing what will happen to my data.

Comment: check the answers here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345678/46541

Comment: Move /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework to the trash

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you updated iTunes and this is the aftermath.

https://www.macrumors.com/2018/12/14/itunes-12-8-1-breaks-safari-on-osx-yosemite/

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks. The tip in this article did the trick for me. And by me, I mean my mother-in-law.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. It looks like iTunes just released an update today that takes care of the problem. I am now able to open Safari and use it as before. Thanks again!