# ITunes 12.8.1.2 does not recognize devices nor see backups

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Running Yosemite 10.10.5 on MacBook Air (early 2014), with Safari v. 10.1.2, iTunes 12.8.1.2, iTunes updated dec 14 2018.
Devices (iPhone, iPad) do not register in iTunes. Are seen in USB device tree in System Information.
In iTunes, preferences, Devices: backups are blank - contains at least 10 for 5 different devices ....
Safari ‘cannot be opened because of a problem’ (no window comes up).

ITunes 12.8. will not install: ‘Newer version already installed’.
ITunes will not delete:’required by OSX’. Timemachine backup will not restore...

I need device connectivity, their backups and this OSX.
Any suggestions ?

Berthe

Dec 17: new iTunes build in App store appeared, it fixes Safari and Photo-connect to device. ITunes not tested yet, but I expect it, too, is fine....

Comment: Btw, Photos 1.0.1 also does not see devices now - forgot to mention that. Bmwill.

Answer (score 1):

[Appears to be issues relating to the new MobileDevice.framework on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345712/safari-on-my-mac-wont-open-because-safari-cannot-be-opened-because-of-a-proble) (I'm aware that the problem is slightly different, but the issues seem related.) I'd recommend upgrading macOS  if you can (it's good practice anyways), and if not, downgrading iTunes or waiting to see if Apple releases a fix.